# RSpec 2 'something.should be`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, rspec2

I came across some horrible looking RSpec 2 test:

```
something.should be
```

Nope, I didn't accidentally forget to cut+paste the rest of the line, 
that's it!

So what's the exact semantic of that?  `should_not be_nil` ?

Please chime in why this is horrible style.

IMHO it's sloppy, not precise, and does not clearly communicate what's required. (it triggers my gag reflex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - according to the docs `object.should.be` equals `object.should_not be_nil`

[Documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/be-matchers), 4th one down in that first list.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration): "We recommend you use the `expect` syntax unless you have a specific reason you prefer the `should` syntax. We have no plans to ever completely remove the `should` syntax but starting
in RSpec 3, a deprecation warning will be issued if you do not explicitly enable it, with the plan to disable it by default in RSpec 4 (and potentially move it into an external gem)."

I believe the equivalent in newer syntax would be:

```
expect(something).to be
```

or more commonly:

```
expect(something).not_to be_false
```

Comment: yes, I know that `expect` is supposed to be used for RSpec 3. 
I'm asking specifically for RSpec 2, as the title mentions :)